# Window attribute when i click button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have problem with callback function I think that this is reason why I have window attribute when I click in button. This is code

```
            function removeProduct(callback) {
            var recordchosen = $(this);          ////////here I have WINDOW instead button
            var recordToDelete = recordchosen.attr("data-id");     
            if (recordToDelete != '') {

                // Send post request with AJAX
                $.post("/Cart/RemoveFromCart", { "albumID": recordToDelete },
                    function (response) {
                        // Success      
                        $('#productCart-' + response.prodID).fadeOut('slow', function () {
                            if (response.productsCart == 0) {
                                $("#cartEmpty").removeClass("hidden");
                            }


                        });
                        var textCart = $("#cartbox").text();
                        var amountCart = (parseInt(textCart) - 1);
                        $("#cartbox").text(amountCart);

                    });
                callback();
                return false;
            };
        };

        $(".removeProduct").click(function () { removeProduct(updateTotal) });
```

Someone know what I do wrong?

Comment: Try: `$(".removeProduct").click(function () { removeProduct.call($(".removeProduct"), updateTotal) });`.Besides, you shouldn't return anything if you have a callback.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that `this` is losing context because the button is not directly invoking `removeProduct`. Instead, you are passing an anonymous function which then calls `removeProduct`. In non-strict mode, javascript will coerce an undefined value of `this` into `window` hence your issue.

To solve it you can use the call approach as mentioned in the comments, although I would make one adjustment:

```
$(".removeProduct").click(function () {
  removeProduct.call(this, updateTotal); 
});
```

Since the anonymous function has the proper context of this, we can call `removeProduct` using `this` from the anonymous function.

I don't want to go into much more detail since this issue is very well documented on this site and online in general, but if you want to read more about how `call` works here is the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call